# How to figure out which items all players in a game of League of Legends currently have in their inventory

Tags: web-scraping, data-retrieval

I am interested in writing a program that needs to know all the currently purchased items in the game by all players. This information wouldn't have to be updated in real time, it could be updated every few minutes. The best solution I could come up with would be to input a screenshot and then look through the image for icons for the different items.

Are there any better ways to get in game information?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can do the screenshot based method with a color bot like Simba (http://villavu.com/ )

But you could also try with WireShark http://www.wireshark.org to reverse the pockets sent by the client to identify items.

You could also poke around in the games memory but that could be a pain.

Comment: Sweet. Thank you for the advice. I had thought about WireShark, but like you said it could be quite a chore to find the information I am looking for. I'll look into Simba later today.